# Show the request from rest api server with c # on gridview

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, rest

I'm connecting with c # to rest api server. and a json output comes as below.

WindowsForms, Model and Repository files are as follows.

1-) In other words, I want to transfer the json data incoming "result" object to the model file and show it on the gridview.

2-) Also, when I make a "Get" request, I want to request a "Body" object with a parameter.
example: {"business_code": "dental"}

**CustomersModel.cs**

```
 namespace HastaTakip.Models
 {
     public class CustomersModel
     {
         public result _result { get; set; }
    
         public class result
         {
             public int id { get; set; }
             public string customer_name { get; set; }
             public string customer_lastname { get; set; }
             public string customer_identity { get; set; }
             public string customer_gender { get; set; }
             public string customer_phone { get; set; }
             public string customer_description { get; set; }
             public bool customer_status { get; set; }
             public string doctor { get; set; }
             public string customer_code { get; set; }
             public string business_code { get; set; }
             public int user_code_id { get; set; }
        }
     }
 }
```

**CustomersRepository.cs**

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HastaTakip.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace HastaTakip.Api
{
    public class CustomersRepository
    {
        public HttpClient _client;
        public HttpResponseMessage _response;
    
        public CustomersRepository()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3000/");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public async Task<CustomersModel> GetList()
        {
            _response = await _client.GetAsync($"customers");
            var json = await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var listCS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomersModel>(json);
            return listCS;
        }
    }
}
```

**WindowsForms.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HastaTakip.Api;
using HastaTakip.Models;

namespace HastaTakip.Forms
{
    public partial class frmCustomerList : Form
    {
        CustomersRepository _repository = new CustomersRepository();

        public frmCustomerList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }

        private async void LoadData()
        {
            var listCS = await _repository.GetList();
            gridControl1.DataSource = listCS;
        }

        private  void frmCustomerList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Json results**

```
{
    "result": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customer_name": "Test1",
        "customer_lastname": null,
        "customer_identity": "54sd45",
        "customer_gender": "Man",
        "customer_phone": null,
        "customer_description": "kkjkjk.",
        "customer_status": null,
        "doctor": null,
        "customer_code": "bcc50586-6960-4766-9468-c9dc55780e40",
        "business_code": "dental",
        "user_code_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "customer_name": "Depron",
        "customer_lastname": null,
        "customer_identity": "564434",
        "customer_gender": "WOMEN",
        "customer_phone": null,
        "customer_description": "record test.",
        "customer_status": null,
        "doctor": null,
        "customer_code": "344865b4-1028-4051-9ec4-71db17414787",
        "business_code": "dental",
        "user_code_id": 1
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the json file you should get back a list or an array but in your model you only have one result the correct way would be:

```
public class CustomersModel
     {
         public List<result> _result { get; set; }           
     }
  public class result
         {
             public int id { get; set; }
             public string customer_name { get; set; }
             public string customer_lastname { get; set; }
             public string customer_identity { get; set; }
             public string customer_gender { get; set; }
             public string customer_phone { get; set; }
             public string customer_description { get; set; }
             public bool customer_status { get; set; }
             public string doctor { get; set; }
             public string customer_code { get; set; }
             public string business_code { get; set; }
             public int user_code_id { get; set; }
        }
```

also i would never use nested classes unless there is a very good reason. and as long as it is not private i don't see a reason here anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. but as you said, I made changes to the code, but it returns "null". Error image : https://ibb.co/3f3f8VP

Comment: actually I noticed that. I'm getting the data but it doesn't export it into "result" in the model.